# Rollback multiple transactions on try catch

Tags: sql-server

Hi i'm learning transactions and i have difficulty trying to understand how do i use rollback when i have multiple transactions with different names. I'm using a try catch to call rollback in case an error occurs

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertFromPDP
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @tempTable TABLE
    (
        Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
        Referencia VARCHAR(15),
        UAP NVARCHAR(20),
        ConsumoInicialWeek01 FLOAT,
        ConsumoInicialWeek02 FLOAT,
        Stock INT,
        PecasPorCaixa INT,
        NumTurnos INT DEFAULT 3,
        NumPab INT DEFAULT 6,
        AlcanceAbastecimento INT DEFAULT 3,
        QtdMin INT DEFAULT 4,
        QtdMax INT DEFAULT 12,
        NumDias INT DEFAULT 5
        UNIQUE (Id)
    )

    INSERT INTO 
        @tempTable  
        (
            Id,
            Referencia,
            UAP,
            ConsumoInicialWeek01,
            ConsumoInicialWeek02,
            Stock,
            PecasPorCaixa
        )
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM 
        viewConsumoPDP

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRAN InsertNotExistsReferenciasFromPDP;

    INSERT INTO 
        Parametros
    SELECT 
        M.Referencia, 
        M.UAP,      
        M.NumTurnos,
        M.NumPab,
        M.AlcanceAbastecimento,
        M.QtdMin,
        M.QtdMax,
        M.NumDias
    FROM 
        @tempTable M    
    WHERE 
        NOT EXISTS 
        (
            SELECT 
                * 
            FROM Parametros P 
            WHERE 
                M.Referencia <> P.Referencia
            AND 
                M.UAP <> P.UAP 
        )

    BEGIN TRAN InsertConsumoFromPDP

    -- TODO--

        COMMIT InsertNotExistsReferenciasFromPDP
        COMMIT InsertConsumoFromPDP
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK InsertNotExistsReferenciasFromPDP
            ROLLBACK InsertConsumoFromPDP
        -- RAISE ERROR --
    END CATCH
END
```

Is there a way to rollback all of the named transactions in just one command without specifying ROLLBACK + Name of the transaction?

Comment: Don't be fooled. Nested transactions do not behave like you think they do. https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION without a savepoint_name or transaction_name rolls back to the beginning of the transaction.
You can find more details at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/rollback-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017